# Quarkus ClassNotFoundException for local dependency

Tags: java, gradle, quarkus

I'm trying to migrate a project to Quarkus. The project has a dependency on a local .jar file. Running the app with Quarkus results in `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`/`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` for classes residing in said  jar.

I'm using gradle as the build tool and the local jar file is added as a dependency using:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

Suppose the library contains some class `Foo` with a static method `init()`, then the following code results in an error:

```java
// From the local jar
import org.somepackage.Foo;

@Startup
@Singleton
public class Main {

  @PostConstruct
  public void initLocalLibrary() {
    Foo.init();
  }

}
```

The exact output is

```
2020-04-19 18:31:21,266 ERROR [io.qua.application] (main) Failed to start application: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/somepackage/Foo
    at Main.initLocalLibrary(Main.java:)
    at Main.initLocalLibrary_Bean.create(Main_Bean.zig:129)
    at Main_Bean.create(Main_Bean.zig:183)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.somepackage.Foo

    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass(QuarkusClassLoader.java:322)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass(QuarkusClassLoader.java:275)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass(QuarkusClassLoader.java:322)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader.loadClass(QuarkusClassLoader.java:275)
    ... 35 more

2020-04-19 18:31:21,302 ERROR [io.qua.dev.DevModeMain] (main) Failed to start Quarkus: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus
    at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.doStart(ApplicationImpl.zig:232)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Application.start(Application.java:90)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.StartupActionImpl.run(StartupActionImpl.java:99)
    at io.quarkus.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.firstStart(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:60)
    at io.quarkus.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.accept(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:236)
    at io.quarkus.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.accept(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:39)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.app.CuratedApplication.runInCl(CuratedApplication.java:131)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.app.CuratedApplication.runInAugmentClassLoader(CuratedApplication.java:84)
    at io.quarkus.dev.DevModeMain.start(DevModeMain.java:113)
    at io.quarkus.dev.DevModeMain.main(DevModeMain.java:54)
```

Running the application without Quarkus works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to replace

`implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`

with

`api fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`